# When add RPSystemBroadcastPickerView to my custom view and send event to it internal button, UI cannot response

Tags: ios, iphone, ios12, replaykit, rpsystembroadcastpickerview

When adding RPSystemBroadcastPickerView to my custom view on iOS 12, and send touch event to its internal button, UI blocked and cannot response any touch event.

Here is my code:
When I receive a notification, I call this method to init my custom view:

```
- (void)presentMyCustomView
{
    MyCustomView *myCustomView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] viewWithTag:kMyCustomViewTag];
    if (!myCustomView)
    {
        myCustomView = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
        myCustomView.tag = kMyCustomViewTag;
        [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:myCustomView];
        [myCustomView release];
    }
}
```

In MyCustomView class's init method, I create RPSystemBroadcoatPickerView and add it to MyCustomView:

```
RPSystemBroadcastPickerView *broadcastPicker = [[RPSystemBroadcastPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.f, 100.f)];
broadcastPicker.preferredExtension = @"xxxxx";
self.broadcastPicker = broadcastPicker;
[self addSubview:broadcastPicker];
[broadcastPicker release];
```

But when I run my project, sometimes UI blocked and all other elements on MyCustomView cannot be touched. RPBroadcastPicker crash log will be found in device logs but not everytime general crash log.

I have used many methods, for example, add broadcastPicker to the key window directly, but cannot help.

Anyone can help me? Many thanks.

Comment: where is the code that fails?

Comment: Nothing failed but UI freeze. RPSystemBroadcastPickerView appeared on my custom view but cannot be touched. Other buttons also cannot be touched.

Comment: From what you are saying, I doubt the problem is in `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` - use a normal button instead, and see if it works.. If not, then you are looking for a bug in a wrong place

Comment: If I only add a normal button, it works fine every time. But if I add RPSystemBroadcastPickerView, sometimes any touch events cannot be received.

Comment: @MichaelYuan, did you got any solution for freeze?

Comment: @iOSLifee yes, here is my solution for UI freeze.
1, Use method swizzling to hook UIViewController's init, viewDidLoad and viewWillDisappear methods. 
2, You can NSLog to see which controller been create and didLoad when use RPSystemBroadcastPickerView.

Comment: @iOSLifee when RPBroadcastPicker crashed, RPBroadcastPickerStandaloneViewController covered on my UI, that's why my UI "freezed". So I will dismiss RPBroadcastPickerStandaloneViewController when send touch event to RPSystemBroadcastPickerView.

Comment: @MichaelYuan, actually my app only freeze on iPhone X and in other devices it's working fine

Comment: @MichaelYuan can you share me that code???

Comment: @iOSLifee This is my demo code:https://github.com/jilaiyuan/RPSystemPickerDemo.git

Answer (score 1):

```
if (@available(iOS 12.0, *)) {
    RPSystemBroadcastPickerView *pickerView = [RPSystemBroadcastPickerView new];
    pickerView.preferredExtension = @"com.apple.sharescreen";
    SEL buttonPressed = NSSelectorFromString(@"buttonPressed:");
    if ([pickerView respondsToSelector:buttonPressed]) {
        [pickerView performSelector:buttonPressed withObject:nil];
    }
}
```